# Why does pausing stop flashvideos from lagging?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, lag, divx

This is a more theoretical question:

When I'm watching larger videos (> 15 min) on the internet via flashplayer or divx, after some minutes, the video quality begins to decrease (like the video starts lagging). When I now press the pause button and resume the playing after a short period of time, like 10 seconds, the video quality is again like normal for another couple of minutes, but then the video quality again decreases, so I have to pause again for some seconds.

My question is, from a software design point-of-view, why does the pausing stop the video from lagging? I thought it could be because the software gets time to refresh its caches, but I would be really interested in the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try youtube.  It shows how is the buffer that serves as the read-ahead buffer is full.  When it is exhausted (due to slower connection) the video will start to degrade and slow down.  Pausing causes read-ahead buffer to fill again.

Comment: Yes, this obviously a reason, but I'm talking about the lagging that occurs even if the read-ahead-buffer is fully loaded.

Comment: Slow CPU?  did you try to take a look at the CPU usage?

Comment: yes, my cpu is not very fast, but it doesn't explain why it becomes better after pausing the video.

Comment: Hm - maybe it is the buffering, and the buffering indicator is showing incorrect data.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a memory problem. When you're thrashing memory - grabbing it, then having to delete more before you can grab again - it affects performance, which in this case looks like the video is lagging